# GoogleFinace convert dd/mm/yy to yy,mm,dd format

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use blew expression in Google SpreadSheet.

```
=min(GoogleFinance("HKDUSD","price",date(A2)-1,date(A2)))
```

But since A2 data is in mm/dd/year format, we need to convert it to yy,mm,dd format as parameter of date().Does Google SpeadSheet has some API to do such convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works if you just add the dates as they are without the date function wrapped around them

```
=min(GoogleFinance("HKDUSD","price",L1-1,L1))
```

[image]

Edited: To answer your follow up question about the date format - a  formulaic workaround  you do uses regex replace and basically just swaps the two capture groups in month and day with this regex "(\w+)/(\w+)":

```
=min(GoogleFinance("HKDUSD","price",REGEXREPLACE(L1,"(\w+)/(\w+)","$2/$1")-1,REGEXREPLACE(L1,"(\w+)/(\w+)","$2/$1")))
```

Comment: But I got below error with your solution! "Error
Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '28/01/2015' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Comment: It seems if I input "28/01/2015" to cell, it will not be converted to date format, but if I input "01/28/2015", then it will be converted to date format so your solution will work. How can I make "28/01/2015" can be convert to date automatically?

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann Can we just convert the dd/mm/yyyy format to datatime object from format menu?